# Strange issue with date and time in php on linux

Tags: php, linux, datetime, sles

i've search a lot but i could not find an answer to this problem. I've set correctly the timezone on the server and for php. As i use "date" commmand on the server it gives me the right answer. But if i use this PHP script:

```
<?php
// include 'cal_config.php';
// include 'cal_matchclass.php';

// $_mail = $_GET["mail"];

$dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $dataTime;
echo "\n".date_default_timezone_get();

?>
```

the date/time it shows me is 6 hours later!
but the timezone is correct (in this case it is Europe/Rome).

Anyone has some suggestions? Pls help because i really cannot understand what's wrong as i set all things right. Thanks all.

This is the output from "date" command on linux:

```
mar  5 ago 2014, 18.06.15, EDT
```

And this is the output from the above php script:

```
2014-08-06 00:06:12
Europe/Rome
```

Comment: how did you set the timezone? did you set the setting for `date.timezone` in php.ini or did you call `date_default_timezone_set()`?

Comment: i used date.timezone in php.ini

Comment: I think you may have your system time set to the incorrect timezone.. what is the output of running the linux command: `date +%Z` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDT = Eastern Daylight Time (UTC - 4 hours)

Europe/Rome = +2.0 hours

Their time sum gives you exactly six hours difference.

Comment: how to change that edt? or what's the problem?

Comment: Refer to your linux distro help on this.

Comment: @ElProbes akond is correct, changing your system timezone is different depending on what flavor of linux you have, though googling for the process should get you pretty good results.

Comment: I thank you all but i googled it lot of time and i did everything i could find to solve this and all seems correct, but the output from php remains wrong. I'll go on googling anyway and i hope to find something useful. Thanks again.